# how can I get libcurl to callback BEFORE it sends some information on a post?

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl, curlpp

I'm uploading information to a server using a post call (using curlpp, but libcurl directly is fine too).

CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION callback gets called from time to time with reports on how much data was send until now. When I upload a file, I see this call being made with very small delta between calls.

I want to get a callback BEFORE each part of data is sent, with the information of how much data is going to be transmitted now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such callbacks in libcurl. CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION will tell you basically that info, but *after* it was sent...

Comment: is there any way to inject such callback (preferably only to a specific instance of easy handler)?

Answer (score 0):

You might use the callback to be set by passing `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` to `curl_easy_setopt()`.

This assumes that the amount of data to be read by this callback function will be the size of the next chunk to be sent.

For details please see here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTREADFUNCTION

Comment: CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_READFUNCTION were the first things I've tried, but while CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION is called multiple times during the upload, neither the read or write callback don't seems to be called. Any ideas why?